# Creating Stacked Bar charts in SSRS

Tags: graph, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-2012

I would like to create a stacked barchart in SSRS.

I have following data.

```
Id  Year value
1  2005  990
1 2006 888
2 2005 986
2 2006 875
3 2005 970
3 2006 865
```

I would like these 3 ids to be displayed in the same bargraph, with years stacked to a particular entity (based on ids). The number of years would be same.

something like below:

```
year 1  year 2           year 1 year 2     year 1 year 2
entity 1                  entity 2          entity 3
```

I tried finding solution online but could not find anything related to it.

Can you please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add row_number to your dataset query and then drag the Id and row_number fields to the Category Groups. Id is at the top of category group. Change the row_number group label to Year field. You will get the expected result.

Comment: Thanks Daniel it is displaying values now .. 3 questions now.. 1) it only shows one year label, is there any way to display all years? 2) and can I customize color for each year for example year 1 for all entities as Yellow, year 2 for all entities as Red.  3) it is possible that one of the entities might not have value (for all the years) is it possible to display no data lable? Thanks once again for your help.

Comment: 1) Right-click row_number on Category Groups window and change the Label to [Year] field, it works properly in my local environment. 2)Right-click the the column and select series properties, go to fill tab. You can use custom expression to control the series color. 3)Yes, it's possible. The column value is determined by the data.

Comment: Thanks Daniel 1 and 2 worked.. for 3 the problem is that I can set the no data label for the entire graph but not for the individual entities when value is null for all the years.

Comment: example: I have 3 entities 1,2,3 and values as 1  2005  990
1 2006 888
2 2005 986
2 2006 875    now I would like to display No data available for Entity 3. Once again thank you so much.

Comment: If you want entity 3 display with no data on your chart. In your database, entity 3 must exist. Example: 1 2005 100, 2 2006 200, 3 null null.

Comment: Got it.. It displays the empty bars, But I was wondering if there is any way to display no data label for these entities.